# $scope property gets updated in test browser, but not in tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

test file:

```
describe('$rootScope', function() {
    describe('$on', function() {
        var credentials = "Basic abcd1234";
        var $scope;
        var $rootScope;
        var $httpBackend;
        ...
        beforeEach(inject(function($injector, $controller, _$rootScope_, $state, _$q_, currentUserService) {
            $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            $httpBackend.when('GET', 'dist/app/login/login.html').respond({'title': 'TEST_TITLE'}, {'A-Token': 'xxx'});
        }));

        ...
        it('should set $scope.title if noAuthorization', function() {
            spyOn($rootScope, '$on');
            $controller('AppCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
            $rootScope.$broadcast("$stateChangeStart");
            $rootScope.$apply();

            expect($rootScope.$on).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect($scope.title).toBe('TEST_TITLE');

        });
    });
});
```

$scope.title is always undefined in my tests. the expect always fails. I've tried $emit, $apply, etc. This is within a controller, inside of a $rootScope.on method.

But if I console log $scope.title inside of the js file, it does show that $scope.title has bene updated.

I should also mention that the function being called is not in $scope, ie it is not `$scope.updateTitle`, it is just `function updateTitle(...)`

I don't feel the actual code is necessary to show because it does it's job. I am just wondering why the $scope in the tests is not getting updated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In a nutshell: don't forget `.andCallThrough()` on the spy. The Jasmine spy needed `andCallThrough()`. Use `element.scope()` to access the correct scope.

```
spyOn(scope, '$apply').andCallThrough();
```

Comment: No luck. It doesn't do anything. I put a callThrough(() for $on, and $apply. And still it is undefined.